# Ubuntu (Desktop + Server) 16.04: adding Ethernet network (LAN)

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ethernet, ip

### Situation:

I have a PC and a server (not virtual machine). I'm completely new to configuring hardware. I need to setup Ethernet network using LAN cable. Ethernet cable is connected directly from PC to the server (without Ethernet switch).

### PC information:

`Operating system:` [Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)
`Architecture:` 64-bit (AMD64)
`Connected to the Internet (wi-fi):` yes (wi-fi)
`Network interfaces ($ ipconfig -a):`

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:18:80:37  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:283996 (283.9 KB)  TX bytes:283996 (283.9 KB)
```

`Network card ($ lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'):`

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

### Server information:

`Model:` [HP ProLiant DL580 G7](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-proliant-dl580-g7-base-xeon-e7520-1-86-ghz-monitor-none-series/specs/) ( [full manual](http://images10.newegg.com/User-Manual/User_Manual_59-107-161.pdf) )
`Operating system:` [Ubuntu Server 16.04.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)
`Architecture:` 64-bit (AMD64)
`Connected to the Internet (wi-fi):` no

### Questions:

How to setup Ethernet network between server and PC?
Is there any specific problems connected to the [specifications](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-proliant-dl580-g7-base-xeon-e7520-1-86-ghz-monitor-none-series/specs/) I have on my server?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### From `Bennett` answer:

In order to connect two machines using Local network (Ethernet) you need to:

#### 1. Connect the LAN cable to the `server` and to the `personal computer`

#### 2. Add network interface to the `server`:

Run `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` in your terminal.

Add this snippet to the file:

```
# My Ethernet interface
auto enp4s0f0
iface enp4s0f0 inet static
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

Save the file using `Ctrl + X` shortcut.

Run `sudo reboot` in your terminal in order to setup new configuration.

#### 3. Add network interface to the `personal computer`:

Run `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` in your terminal.

Add this snippet to the file:

```
# My Ethernet interface
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.10.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

Save the file using `Ctrl + X` shortcut.

Run `sudo reboot` in your terminal in order to setup new configuration.

#### 4. Congratulations! Your Ethernet connection between `server` and `personal computer` is setup

#### 5. P.S:

Notice, that you need to configure snippet of the interface for yourself.
Here is a template:

```
# My Ethernet interface
auto <interface_name>
iface <interface_name> inet static
address <ip_address>
netmask <netmask>
network <network_address>
broadcast <broadcast_address>
```

Where:

`<interface_name>`: name of the interface (run `ifconfig -a` to get the list of interfaces)
`<ip_address>`: IPv4 address of the interface (template: `ip1.ip2.ip3.ip4`)
`<netmask>`: netmask of the interface (usually `255.255.255.0`)
`<network_address>`: IPv4 address of the network of the interface (`ip1.ip2.ip3.0`)
`<broadcast_address>`: IPv4 address of the broadcast of the interface (`ip1.ip2.ip3.255`)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to statically assign IP addresses for both machines.

PC: 192.168.10.1    255.255.255.0

Server: 192.168.10.2    255.255.255.0

For headles Ubuntu server network config you will need to edit /etc/network/interfaces 
Useful article [here](https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/install/configure_networking.html)
Example config for server:

```
# The primary network interface 
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static 
address 192.168.10.2 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 192.168.10.0 
broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

You won't have internet with this configuration because routing would need to be configured through your PC.

Also, not likely but there could be a need for a crossover cable because you're going device to device though most modern NICs handle this automatically.

Note: you could limit the address range with CIDR 192.168.10.0/30 only allowing the two devices.

Comment: I think you forgot the article link.