# Server 16.04: configuring Wi-Fi connection (USB adapter)

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, internet, ethernet

### Edit:

`sudo ifdown wlx000e0008833e && sudo ifup -v wlx000e0008833e`:

```
Configuring interface wlx000e0008833e=wlx000e0008833e (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ IF_BOND_SLAVES=
+ [  ]
+ [  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exit
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.0.50/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255       dev wlx000e0008833e label wlx000e0008833e
/bin/ip link set dev wlx000e0008833e   up
 /bin/ip route add default via 192.168.0.1  dev wlx000e0008833e onlink 
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ [  ]
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ip
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
```

`dmesg | grep wlx`:

```
[   16.181623] mt7601u 1-6:1.0 wlx000e0008833e: renamed from wlan0
[   16.309273] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000e0008833e: link is not ready
[  187.708914] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000e0008833e: link is not ready
[ 1333.308500] mt7601u 1-6:1.0 wlx000e0008833e: renamed from wlan0
[ 1333.502331] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000e0008833e: link is not ready
[ 1357.986859] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000e0008833e: link is not ready
```

### Situation:

I have a server with Ubuntu Server 16.04 operating system. I need to connect it to the wifi network using usb wifi adapter, but I have some issues tuning that.

When I was pluging in usb wifi adapter and runing `ifconfig -a` I could see this information (before **settings I made**):

```
wlx000e0008833e Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:00:08:83:3e  
                BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

### Wifi configuration:

- `network name (ssid):` developer-modem
- `password:` cHc0h6qZ3Hv8wscF
- `security:` WPA/WPA2
- `IPv4 address:` 192.168.0.109

#### Information about the same network when I connect to my PC (`Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 AMD64`):

[image: Network Information]

#### Information about my modem:

[image]

### Settings I made:

I added this script to `/etc/networks/interfaces`:

```
# The wifi network interface 
auto wlx000e0008833e
iface wlx000e0008833e inet static 
address 192.168.0.109 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 192.168.0.0 
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid developer-modem
wpa-psk cHc0h6qZ3Hv8wscF
```

### Problem:

When I ping `192.168.0.109` (my modem) I get responses:

```
PING 192.168.0.109 (192.168.0.109) 56(84) bytes of data:
64 bytes from 192.168.0.109: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.109: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.0.109: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
--- 192.168.0.109 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3997 ms
```

When I ping `192.168.0.1` (1st dns-nameserver) I get responses with error:

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data:
From 192.168.0.109 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.109 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
...
From 192.168.0.109 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3017 ms
```

When I ping `8.8.8.8` (2nd dns-nameserver) I get an error:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

When I ping any other address (e.g `www.google.com`) I get an error:

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

### Questions:

I am not sure that everything is setup, cause I just changed `/etc/network/interfaces` (see changes above) and nothing else.

How to fix this issue?

Thanks for help

Comment: I suggest that you remove the network and broadcast ines and then do: `sudo ifdown wlx000e0008833e && sudo ifup -v wlx000e0008833e` Next, edit your question to show the result. I assume the password is redacted as usually the minimum length is 8 characters.

Comment: Also, if your Desktop already has x.109, you can not also give the same x.109 to the server.

Comment: @chili555 I removed network from `/etc/network/interfaces`. After running that command I got `Unknown interface wlx000e0008833e`

Comment: @chili555 My desktop has x.109 and server has x.109 (cause I has just one modem and one wifi adapter). So I need to remove Network Interface from my Desktop to have Interner connection on Server?

Comment: If you look around in the configuration pages of the modem/router, isn't there a provision for DHCP? Is there a DHCP range? x.100 to x.150 or some such?

Comment: @chili555 Yes, there is. DHCP IP Pool:  192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you change the interfaces file on the server to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The wifi network interface 
auto wlx000e0008833e
iface wlx000e0008833e inet static 
address 192.168.0.50
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid developer-modem
wpa-psk cHc0h6qZ3Hv8wscF
```

Reboot.

Did the server connect? Check:

```
ping -c3 192.168.0.1
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: It didn't connect. When I ping `192.168.0.1` it gives me responses with `Destination Host Unreachable`. And when I ping `www.ubuntu.com` it gives me `ping: unknown host www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo ifdown wlx000e0008833e && sudo ifup -v wlx000e0008833e `  The -v for verbose should give us some clues as to what's going wrong. Also post: `dmesg | grep wlx`

Comment: Added logs from `sudo ifdown wlx000e0008833e && sudo ifup -v wlx000e0008833e` and `dmesg | grep wlx`. See **edit**

Comment: Is wpa_supplicant installed? `sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant | grep Version`

Comment: `wpa_supplicant` is not installed

Comment: Please hook up the ethernet, do: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant` Reboot and tell us if it's now working.

Comment: Etherent is already setup (I use it for SSH connection between my PC and Server). I have Internet connection on PC but I don't have it on Server. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061519/ubuntu-desktop-server-16-04-adding-ethernet-network-lan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81137/discussion-between-chili555-and-maks-mihalchuk).