# Server 16.04: install APT package + depends OFFLINE (using terminal)

Tags: 16.04, server, package-management, software-installation, offline

### Situation:

I have a server with **Ubuntu Server 16.04** set on it. I need to install APT package `network-manager` to connect to Wi-Fi network.

** I have also PC that is connected to the Internet (if it's needed).*

### Problem:

It's impossible to install that package by running `sudo apt install network-manager`, cause I have no Internet yet. But I have no idea how to do that in different way.

### Computers:

#### Server:

`Operating System`: Ubuntu Server 16.04 (AMD64)
`Internet`: no

#### PC:

`Operating System`: Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 (AMD64)
`Internet`: yes

### Questions:

How to download APT package with all depends on the computer with no Internet connection?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can connect to a wireless network by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and you don't need Network Manager: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal/464552#464552

Comment: @chili555 I [tried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061823/server-16-04-configuring-wi-fi-connection-usb-adapter) using this method but I had some issues with that

Comment: Please tell us what they were; perhaps they are fixable.

Comment: @chili555 here they are: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061823/server-16-04-configuring-wi-fi-connection-usb-adapter

Comment: Did you see my comment there? Did you try it? Please post the results I requested there.